# Integrating multiple functions to get one function?

Tags: integration

I have an equation in terms of $ d^2x/dt^2$, $d^2y/dt^2$, and $d^2z/dt^2$, and I want to integrate it to find $x(t)$, but I'm having trouble wrapping my mind around how I would perform that integration. Would I just treat the $d^2y/dt^2$ and $d^2z/dt^2$ terms as constants or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

So you have the vector
$$
\ddot u = (\ddot x, \ddot y, \ddot z)
$$
which means
$$
\dot u(t) 
= \int\limits_{t_0}^t \ddot u (\tau) \, d\tau + \dot u (t_0)
$$
and
\begin{align}
u(t) 
&= \int\limits_{t_0}^t \dot u (\tau) \, d\tau + u (t_0) \\
&= 
\int\limits_{t_0}^t
\left( 
\int\limits_{t_0}^\tau \ddot u (\tau') \, d\tau' + \dot u (t_0) \right)
\, d\tau + u (t_0) \\
&= 
\int\limits_{t_0}^t
\int\limits_{t_0}^\tau \ddot u (\tau') \, d\tau' \, d\tau + \dot u (t_0)
\, (t-t_0) + u (t_0)
\end{align}

If you are just interested in $x(t)$, just replace the vector $u = (x,y,z)$ with the component $x$ in the above equations.

Comment: Can you explain the use of $\tau$ as an integration variable? I've seen that elsewhere but I have never understood its use.

Comment: PS - forgot to say thanks for your reply! Much appreciated.

Comment: It is a variation of the $t$ variable, which already shows up as the upper bound of the integral, so one uses $\tau$ (tau) for the integration variable to keep them independent.